# capistrano deployment

Tags: capistrano

I udpated the code on my development machine, then deploy it to production machine(git server and production server are on the same machine). from the brower i can see the change i made was not there.

I went to cap's current folder, i can see all the code are updated, but in the latest release folder, the code are still old version. I've ran

```
cap deploy:cleanup
cap deploy
```

still got the same result.

then i tried to remove all the code from my development machine, and use git clone to get the branch from git server found out everything is alright.

in cap's deploy.rb, i already defined:

```
set :branch, 'inventoryTrakcing'
```

so it should work. is that because the git problem? i've committed all the changes why it still won't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted the code from deploy.rb you might have a typo in the branch name.